# Change collection view constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, swift3

I have create a collection view in my storyboard and add constraints. Now I need to change the collection view constraint for a specific condition and I want to do it programmatically in my class. I have an IBOutlet for the collection view. What parameter needs to be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the constraints normally in the collection view
2. Select the
       constraint you want to modify, hold Control and drag to your class
3. When you want your constraint to be
       changed, type `nameOfYourConstraint.constant = 100 // Int`

Answer (score 1):

First create `IBOutlet` of constraints required to changed by dragging to `ViewController`

The `constant` value needs to be cahnged, e.g.:

`self.outlet.constant = 50`

Don't forget to call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded` after modifying the constant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create IBOutlets of the constraints, and update the constraints value according to your condition.